# Website does not automatically fit to iphone screen

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari, webkit, web-applications

The following code does not fit onto the iphone screen;
how do I have to define the viewport?

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<div id="karteu" style="background: url('../customer/Karten/karte1.jpg') no-repeat left center;width:714px;height:540px;" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Normally the site should be zoomed, so i first should see the website in small, and then be able to zoom that i see it in the original size, but in my case it does not, when i call the site, the zoom is, that the image has this original size already, and that i have to scroll, but i dont want to scroll,...i want to use the normal safari mobile zoom and then scroll

The solution at the bottom does not zoom anything.
I want to see the overview of the image at the beginning.
Then i want to be able to zoom with the normal safari zoom functions,..

Comment: you might want to edit your post with some more information

Comment: @oezi, @Ondrej: The question was badly formatted; now fixed.

Comment: Isn't iPhone's resolution 480x320? Can you display 714x540 DIV on that screen? I'm just guessing why it doesn't fit...

Answer (score 9):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Above answer works! Only thing is, you have to also make your width = 100% !! Had to go into the code in Dreamweaver, which I use, and change the css style sheet to width of the container is not 320 pixels, but 100%. Now it works beautifully on both my ipod touch and the android phone.

Comment: This was superb. Repped. You can even have `minimum-scale=0.77`

Comment: This viewport syntax will work in aaaaaalllllllmost all browsers. But not (I discovered) the Cordova embedded one. The correct delimited in viewport content is comma, not semicolon. http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/11/23/make-sure-to-use-correct-meta-viewport-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

use the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=*your site width*, initial-scale=0.30">
```

works for both tablet and mobile