# Website width doesn't automatically fit to iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

I want my site's width to automatically fit on the iPhone portrait screen (testing on an iPhone 5). I currently have the width CSS set to 100% and am using this meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

This technique was recommended by this question: [Website does not automatically fit to iphone screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673294/website-does-not-automatically-fit-to-iphone-screen)

It doesn't work for me though.  The site width is still way wider than the iPhone portrait screen.

How can I get the site width to automatically fit on the iPhone portrait screen?

Comment: Do you have a hosted example? In what way is it too wide? Is it zoomed out or is content hanging off the viewport?

Comment: No, sorry, it's a protected client site.  It looks like it's actually the header image that's causing it to be too wide. Trying to determine if I can make that fit the iPhone screen width as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure the viewport is configured correctly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Make sure you don't have content that is wider than the viewport.

For instance if you have an image that is wider than the viewport set the CSS to

```
max-width:100%;
```

Comment: I added that to the header image that was causing the problems and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just be off a little. This is what works for me.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work for me either. :( Site is still way too wide. Almost 2.5 times as wide as the iPhone 5 portrait width.